# WordPress: Make use of native video support within theme files?

Tags: wordpress, video, themes, mediaelement.js

Now as WordPress natively supports videos in posts using MediaPlayer.js, I wonder how I can make use of that within my theme files?

Comment: Really no one that has a clue? Was expecting tons of people to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Wordpress native player Mediaelement.js inside your theme you can implement any of the methods below:

1. If using HTML5, simply add the video using `<video>` tag, rest all Wordpress will take care of it.
2. Use `do_shortcode('[video src="video-source.mp4"]')`
3. Use `wp_video_shortcode( $attr )` where `$attr` is the attribute of the video shortcode.

Also you should have the correct version of Wordpress that support Mediaelement.js as their native player (as old versions don't)